# Tensorflow Autoencoder with 0 hidden units learns something

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder

I am currently running some tests with simple Autoencoders. I wrote an Autoencoder myself entirely in Tensorflow and in addition copied and pasted the code from this keras blog entry: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html (just to have a different Autoencoder implementation).

When I was testing different architectures, I started with a single layer and a couple of hidden units in this layer. I noticed that when I reduce the number of hidden units to only a single (!) hidden unit, I still get the same training and test losses I get with bigger architectures (up to a couple of thousand hidden units). In my data, the worst loss is 0.5. Any architecture I've tried achieves ~ 0.15.

Just out of curiosity, I reduced the number of hidden units in the only existing hidden layer to zero (which I know doesn't make any sense). However, I still get a training and test loss of 0.15. I assumed that this strange behavior might be due to the bias in the decoding layer (when I reconstruct the input). Initially, I've set the bias variable (in TF) to trainable=True. So now I guess even without any hidden units, the model still learns the bias in the decoding layer which might lead to the reduction of my loss from 0.5 to 0.15.

In the next step, I set the bias in the decoding layer to trainable=False. Now the model (with no hidden units) doesn't learn anything, just as I would have expected it(loss=0.5).  With one hidden unit,however, I again get test and training losses of around 0.15.

Following this line of thought, I set the bias in the encoding layer to trainable=False, since I wanted to avoid that my architecture only learns the bias. So now, only the weights of my autoencoder are trainable. This still works for a single hidden unit (and of course just a single hidden layer). Surprisingly, this only works in case of a single-layer network. As soon as I increase the number of layers (independent of the numbers of hidden units), the network again doesn't learn anything (in case only the weights get updated).

All the things I reported are true for the training loss as well as for the test loss (in a completely independent dataset the machine never sees). This makes it even more curious to me.

My question is: How can it happen that I learn as much from a 1 node "network" as from a bigger one (both for training and testing)? Second, how can it be that even larger nets seem to never overfit (training and test error slightly change, but are always comparable). Any suggestions would be very helpful!
Thanks a lot! 
Nils

Comment: Is the training/validation dataset balanced?